# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hue

I'm trying to run some scala jar via hue web interface.
When submitting the job, it's failing with the folloring error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit
```

and the full log:

```
2017-08-24 08:31:49,438  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2017-08-24 08:31:49,438  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
2017-08-24 08:31:49,438  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
2017-08-24 08:31:49,470  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W
2017-08-24 08:31:49,470  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@:start:
2017-08-24 08:31:49,483  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] Start action [0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2017-08-24 08:31:49,516  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] Added into spark action configuration mapred.child.env=SPARK_HOME=.,HDP_VERSION=2.6.3.0-57
2017-08-24 08:31:50,421  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] Trying to get job [job_1503473462790_0052], attempt [1]
2017-08-24 08:31:50,437  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] checking action, hadoop job ID [job_1503473462790_0052] status [RUNNING]
2017-08-24 08:31:50,439  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] [***0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5***]Action status=RUNNING
2017-08-24 08:31:50,439  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] [***0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5***]Action updated in DB!
2017-08-24 08:31:50,451  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5
2017-08-24 08:32:00,098  INFO CallbackServlet:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] callback for action [0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5]
2017-08-24 08:32:00,154  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] Trying to get job [job_1503473462790_0052], attempt [1]
2017-08-24 08:32:00,244  INFO SparkActionExecutor:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] action completed, external ID [job_1503473462790_0052]
2017-08-24 08:32:00,247  WARN SparkActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] Launcher ERROR, reason: Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain], main() threw exception, org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit
2017-08-24 08:32:00,247  WARN SparkActionExecutor:523 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] Launcher exception: org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.run(SparkMain.java:222)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:58)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SparkMain.main(SparkMain.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:170)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:164)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 16 more

2017-08-24 08:32:00,293  INFO ActionEndXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
2017-08-24 08:32:00,358  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] Start action [0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
2017-08-24 08:32:00,358  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] [***0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@Kill***]Action status=DONE
2017-08-24 08:32:00,358  INFO ActionStartXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[energia] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[kafka-scala] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] [***0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@Kill***]Action updated in DB!
2017-08-24 08:32:00,435  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@Kill] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@Kill
2017-08-24 08:32:00,435  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W
2017-08-24 08:32:00,435  INFO WorkflowNotificationXCommand:520 - SERVER[BigData] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5] No Notification URL is defined. Therefore nothing to notify for job 0000025-170823093043124-oozie-oozi-W@spark-8ee5
```

Some help, please?

Comment: Did SPARK_HOME set on your environment?

Comment: @FaigB yes. it is

Answer (score 2):

This could be a quick solution.
In your hue workflow window, go to the workspace folder by clicking on the file icon on the top right. Create a 'lib' folder there if one does not exist already.

Go to SPARK_HOME folder in local system ( /usr/hdp/2.5../spark/lib ) and check all the available jars there. Upload these jars to the lib folder in your workspace.
If in case you want to run pyspark jobs, upload the jars in 'python' folder in the spark home.

Rerun the workflow.

P.S: I suppose these jars can be added to the sharelib folder in oozie shared libraries and update the oozie library. (Check for the command online). This might solve the problem of adding these jars to every workflow folders.